# What's the purpose of the sBIT chunk in the PNG file?

Tags: c, png, libpng

Practically, I don't understand the use of the sBIT chunk in an PNG file.

I'm storing PNG files from an 11 bits/channel RGB source, so I dutifully set the sBIT chunk in my (c) code:

```
...
png_color_8 sig_bit;

sig_bit.gray = 0;
sig_bit.alpha = 0;
sig_bit.red = 11;
sig_bit.green = 11;
sig_bit.blue = 11;

png_set_sBIT(png_ptr, info_ptr, &sig_bit);
...
/* save the png */
```

When the images are viewed a windows viewer (native Vista picture viewer/Paint.net), the lower 8 bits are truncated, so I only can see the upper 3 bits.  I would have thought the `sBIT` chunk would automagically instruct readers to left shift the pixels by 5 bits to MSB justify the data for display.  Doesn't seem to be the case.

When I open the png files in my code that either have or don't have an sBIT chunk, and do the following:

```
png_color_8p sig_bit;
if (png_get_valid(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_INFO_sBIT)) {
    png_get_sBIT(png_ptr, info_ptr, &sig_bit);
    png_set_shift(png_ptr, sig_bit);
}
```

The pixel data is the same.

*What is the use model of the sBIT chunk?  Can I somehow use the `sBIT` chunk to MSB justify the pixel data for viewing, but see the "original" data for numerical analysis?*

Comment: What's the bit depth specified in the IHDR chunk? [sBIT is not allowed to exceed that value](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11sBIT); if you're not using a bit depth of 16, that may be why it's not working as you intended.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen 16: I st the IHDR with `png_set_IHDR(img->p, img->i, width, height, 16, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);`

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Based on the link you posted, I'm forced to wonder: Is the `sBIT` chunk just a means to provide a bit mask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sBIT Chunk tells the decoder the number of significant bits in the pixel data. In essence, it tells the decoder that the data has already been shifted left to fit in a standard bit depth. E.g. For your case of 11-bit data, you should have shifted the pixels left by 5 bits and stored them as 16-bits per pixel. The decoder will see that out of the 16-bits in each color, only the top 11 are significant, so that it can potentially recompress the image in a new format knowing that there are only 11 useful bits out of the 16.

Comment: Okay ... so how do I read the data? The `png_set_shift()` seems to left shift, is there a right shift function in the `pnglib` API?

Comment: If you've got a properly formed PNG file, you should be able to ignore the sBIT chunk and still display the image correctly because the bits have been shifted already. I wrote my own PNG codec, so I don't know anything about pnglib. The point is that the pixel data needs to be properly formed already and the sBIT chunk is just a hint for the decoder if it cares to know more details.

Comment: When calling png_set_shift() prior to reading the file then libpng will right shift the data. The function that does this is png_do_unshift()
(Unfortunately that's all it does which prevents me from transforming 8-bit data to 4-bit packed)

Answer (score 0):

Your source has the bit depth of 11, and you’re creating a 16-bit-depth PNG image out of it. So you should set the bits, from the most significant bit to the least, to be: <sup>MSB</sup>`XXXX XXXX XXX0 0000`<sup>LSB</sup><sub>2</sub>, where the 11 `X`’s are from the source.

“[A decoder need not pay attention to the `sBIT` chunk](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Chunks.html#C.sBIT)” **to show**  the created image, as `XXX XXXX XXXX`<sub>2</sub> in the bit depth of 11 and `XXXX XXXX XXX0 0000`<sub>2</sub> in the bit depth of 16 are the same value.

To extract the source bits out, you would want to right-shift the bits by (16－11<sub>`sBIT`</sub>). Note: *libpng* will do the job for you if you do `png_set_shift()` **with the `sBIT` value** before reading the image data; or do `png_read_png()` with the `PNG_TRANSFORM_SHIFT` flag. Well, to answer the question: **that**’s the purpose.